# Comma placementin this sentence

Tags: punctuation, commas

I've been placing the comma in this sentence back and forth for a while now and I'm still not sure where to best place it.

The sentence is: *The worst-case scenario is that X happens.*

I feel like a comma would be very fitting here, but I'm unsure where.

- The worst-case scenario, is that X happens.

or

- The worst-case scenario is, that X happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the comma completely. It's not required.
Neither clause can exist on their own with your placements of the comma.

Replacing the commas with full stops makes this a little clearer.

> 1. The worst case scenario. Is that X happens.
> 2. The worse case scenario is. That X happens.

1. The first sentence is missing a verb and an object.
2. The second sentence is missing a subject. The first sentence, though grammatical, is semantically wrong.

---

You should be able to replace the commas with full stops (and potentially restore an ellipsis)

> <strike>The page displayed a list of vegetables, ordered by color</strike>
>   My original example was bad, the comma was optional.

The comma here can be replaced with a full stop to form two sentences. Context is still required for the second sentence, but part of the sentence can be [removed to avoid repetition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ellipsis).

> My original example was bad. The comma [in that example] was optional.